# Need to get an output value to a variable in powershell

Tags: powershell

my Output is like this

```
MPIO Disk    System Disk  LB Policy    DSM Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MPIO Disk0   Disk 1       RR           Microsoft DSM
```

how can we get only `LB policy` in a variable to get it in `csv` output

Comment: Is it output from `mpclaim -s -d` command? Supposedly fixed-length columns `MPIO Disk` (13), `System Disk` (13), `LB Policy` (13), `DSM Name` (rest of line) or another output mask?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you're getting the output from? An exe, or other non-PoSH method?

Answer (score 0):

If this output is created by format-table you should be able to use `$x."LB Policy"` to get it:

```
$x = your-cmdlet
$x."LB Policy"
```

This should output only this value.

If this is fixed text you most probably have to parse it to get your result.

Comment: I am not getting any results out for $x."LB Policy"